# Refresh of udev rules directory does not work

Tags: usb, services, reboot, udev, devices

I try to edit, remove and create rules in udev. For some reason, those rules are not activated, even when I try the known solutions-

1. Udevadm control --reload-rules
2. Udevadm trigger
3. Just reset the the udev service.

It only works when I reboot the machine (which means that the rules are written correctly).  What should I do in order to enforce an immediate enforcement of rules?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

just worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

One thing to remember, you need to dis- and re-connect the USB device to have the new rule(s) apply

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as ubuntu20.